# Generating .jar executable from gradle cucumber project

Tags: gradle, jar, cucumber, executable

I have a simple framework where I only have the a feature file and the step definition associated. All coded with gradle.

How can I generate a .jar file where the feature file can be executed instead of using gradle cucumber gradle?

I want a simple user to run the test without installing almost anything.

Comment: Do you want to wrap everything together in one jar file? so that the user will be able to use jar without configuring anything else?

Comment: Yes that's it! @George I don't want to see him the code, only be able to execute the cucumber test in one command